# Cloudant support of XML

Tags: xml, json, cloudant

Have XML interfaces and data I need to support. Trying to decide if I could do that in Cloudant to take advantage of  DBaaS operational advantages. I could take in the XML, convert to JSON and store in Cloudant, then convert back to XML  to respond to a request. I've heard that the overhead of doing these sorts of conversions between XML and JSON are in the range of 20%. Is using Cloudant as a backend datastore for XML interfaces practical versus using native XML databases?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a l[ist or show function](https://cloudant.com/blog/building-custom-dashboards-with-geckoboard-and-cloudant/) to convert Cloudant responses to XML but, unless you have a requirement for your clients to communicate directly with Cloudant, you'd be better off doing the conversion in your application tier. Besides this, the approach seems practical.